# how to get the integer value of a single pyserial byte in python

Tags: python, pyserial

I'm using pyserial in python 2.7.5 which according to the [docs](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/pyserial_api.html):

> read(size=1)
>   Parameters: 
>   size – Number of bytes to read.
>   Returns:
>   Bytes read from the port.
>   Read size bytes from the serial port. If a timeout is set it may return less characters as requested. With no timeout it will block until the requested number of bytes is read.
>
> Changed in version 2.5: Returns an instance of bytes when available (Python 2.6 and newer) and str otherwise.

Mostly I want to use the values as hex values and so when I use them I use the following code:

```
ch = ser.read()
print ch.encode('hex')
```

This works no problem.

But now I'm trying to read just ONE value as an integer, because it's read in as a string from serial.read, I'm encountering error after error as I try to get an integer value.

For example:

```
print ch
```

prints nothing because it's an invisible character (in this case chr(0x02)).

```
print int(ch)
```

raises an error

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\x02'
```

trying `print int(ch,16)`, `ch.decode()`, `ch.encode('dec')`, `ord(ch)`, `unichr(ch)` all give errors (or nothing).

In fact, the only way I have got it to work is converting it to hex, and then back to an integer:

```
print int(ch.encode('hex'),16)
```

this returns the expected `2`, but I know I am doing it the wrong way. How do I convert a a chr(0x02) value to a 2 more simply?

Believe me, I have searched and am finding ways to do this in python 3, and work-arounds using imported modules. Is there a native way to do this without resorting to importing something to get one value?

edit: I have tried `ord(ch)` but it is returning `90` and I KNOW the value is `2`, 1) because that's what I'm expecting, and 2) because when I get an error, it tells me (as above)

Here is the code I am using that generates `90`

```
count = ser.read(1)
print "count:",ord(ch)
```

the output is `count: 90`

and as soon as I cut and pasted that code above I saw the error `count != ch`!!!!

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `ord` function.  What you have in your input is a `chr(2)` (which, as a constant, can also be expressed as '\x02').

```
i= ord( chr(2) )
i= ord( '\x02' )
```

would both store the integer 2 in variable `i`.

Comment: Thanks Mario (and mattexx, you were beaten by seconds), I did try ord, but I passed the wrong variable. That is the answer I was after. Thanks again! I'll accept it when I can

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to use `ord()`

```
ch = '\x02'
print ord(ch)
=> 2
```

Comment: thanks mattexx, that's what I was looking for, I was just doing it wrong, ie I had tried `ord` but I was passing it the wrong variable